# what is the Usage Priorities between "/usr/local/cuda" in system and "cudatoolkit" in conda envs?

Tags: python, conda

I am using CUDA 10.0 in my system. But I want to use CUDA 9.0 in a certain project. 
So I conda create one envs for this project with the packages needed, including ***cudatoolkit 9.0***.

I am a little confused about that when I am running the code, which cuda will be covered. "***/usr/local/cuda***" in system or "***cudatoolkit 9.0***" in my conda envs?

Is there ***usage priority*** for "cudatoolkit 9.0" over "/usr/local/cuda"?

And what are relations between ***GLOBAL*** system configuration and ***LOCAL*** conda envs configuration? If I am weak in this kind of questions(global vs local), what kinds of knowledge should I learn...

Comment: In my experience, software installed via conda will generally use the `cudatookit` installed by conda, in that env, not what is in `/usr/local/cuda`.  I'm sure there are ways to circumvent this, but its what I would consider typical.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for your response~ Is there some ways to show which version of cuda I am using in my code running environment? I installed CUDA 9.0 from ".run" format file beside CUDA 10.0 before separately, and I directed CUDA 9.0 to a certain conda env when I activate it. When I run "nvcc -V" in that env's terminal, it can return 'cuda 9.0' rightly. But when I install cuda 9.0 via "conda install cudatoolkit=9.0", command "nvcc -V" also return "cuda 10.0". So I don't know which version of cuda I am using in effect.

Comment: I would use `conda list|grep "cudatoolkit"`.  the conda install of `cudatoolkit` generally doesn't install `nvcc`, and also, the `nvcc` that will be found when you type `nvcc`  will be a function of how your `PATH` environment variable is set up, which isn't necessarily controlled by conda.

Comment: Get it. Thank you very much~ It seems that conda env is a totally separate code running space in our system.

Comment: I always thought that was the point of a conda env